# Reuse mustache.php in mustache.js

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache, mustache.php

I recently started to use Mustache and I'm in a position where I need to reuse PHP templates also in JS.
Although I compiled templates into JS, sometimes is more convenient to just embed templates like this

```
<script type="text/template" id="my-tpl">
  {{foo}}
</script><!-- /#my-tpl -->
```

(and then use from JS).

The problem starts now: since I'm displaying this from Mustache.php, the `{{foo}}` variable is parsed, therefore is not available from JS anymore. The only solution I found is to use different template tags (e.g. `<% foo %>`) for JS, but then this will block the not quite reusable between languages.

So, my question is: it is possible to display a mustache template inside of a mustache template? Did I miss something in the docs? Or it's just not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also switch to different template tags just before the embedded template, and then back after you're done:

```
something awesome with {{ tags }}!

{{=[[[ ]]]=}}
<script type="text/template" id="my-tpl">
  {{foo}}
</script>
[[[={{ }}=]]]

back again with more {{ tags }}!
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thank you!